# Integrated celery beat within Django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, data-integrity, database-normalization

I just started a project to try and get a very simple Django Celery project up and going. Since I'm mainly just trying to see how it works, here's what my settings look like:

```
BROKER_TRANSPORT = "django"
CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER = "djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"
```

I've tested posting tasks with `apply_async()` and by scheduling them in the Django admin site and both work great.

The only problem I'm currently seeing is that I need to run two separate processes to test my tasks, `django runserver` and `django celerybeat`. When I change a periodic task, I need to restart the `celerybeat` process to make it reload. Is there any way that I can run the `celerybeat` process integrated with `runserver` so as to avoid having to remember to start the other process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used it myself, but it appears that you should check out the [django-supervisor](https://github.com/rfk/django-supervisor) project. My understanding is it can be configured to automatically reload content for any number of concurrently running processes that are run with your webserver.

Alternatively, you could use celery 2.5's --autoreload feature. More details on this in [the release notes](http://ask.github.com/celery/whatsnew-2.5.html#experimental-support-for-automatic-module-reloading).